# Where Does Oracle's Original Import Utility (imp) Search For Dump Files?

Tags: oracle

As I don't see a parameter for a directory like `impdp`, where does `imp` search for the dump files that are specified by the `FILE` parameter?

I've searched through the Oracle's documentation for the original import utility and I don't see anything that says where it searches for the dump files.
[Original Import Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-original-import-utility.html#GUID-B14E7C9A-9D1B-451C-9826-1A5567149852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imp` is an operating system utility and is invoked from operating system command prompt. By default, it searches for the file in current directory (the one you're in while running the `imp` executable).

If you specify the path to the file, then it is obvious.

---

If you used more recent Data Pump Import, then you'd have to specify the `directory` parameter which points to a directory, Oracle object that points to a file system directory.  It is usually located on the database server. Directory (the Oracle object) is owned by `SYS` who then grants read and/or write privileges to database users who will be using that directory.

---

Everything above means that: `imp` can use dump files locally, while - for the Data Pump utilities - you don't even have to have access to the physical directory; someone else (such as a DBA) might manipulate files, put them into (filesystem) directory so that you could use them.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, is it just me or does it seem like `imp` does not like spaces in the file path?

Comment: @mgdev Have you used double quotes around the file path or, alternatively, used an escape character \ before each space? If so then that is not an issue with `imp` but it is a standard requirement for using spaces in the arguments for console commands.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference (escaping the space and with or without the quotes). To give you some context, I'm writing a Powershell script that calls `imp`. `FILE="C:\Dump Files\dump_file.dmp"`. When I execute the script it will return something like this. `IMP-00002: failed to open C:\Dump.DMP for read`